# Animate jquery on same page and another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Animate jQuery on same page and another page.

```
var jump=function(e)
{

       if (e){
           var $height = -100;
           e.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr("href");
       }else{

           var $height = 300;
           var target = location.hash;
       }

       $('html, body').animate({

           scrollTop: $(target).offset().top + $height
       },1500,function()
       {
           location.hash = target;
       });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('.navbar-nav .menu-item-type-custom a[href^=#], .offer-sidebar .menu-item-type-custom a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);
     if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.scrollTo(0, 0); 
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show()
            jump()
        }, 1);
    }
}); 
 <div class="nav">
         <a href="http://www.exmaple.com/"> Home </a>
         <a href="http://www.exmaple.com/contact"> Contact </a> 
         <a href="#footer"> Footer </a> // working fine
         <a href="http://www.exmaple.com/#aboutus"> About us </a> // Not work
   </div>
```

On Home Page aboutus will scroll down about us section on same page (not working) and On Contact page it working and jump on home page scroll to about us section.
Can any one help to work with full url on same page and another page?

Comment: No need of / there `<a href="http://www.exmaple.com#footer"> Footer </a>` // will work

Comment: Please see my question edit.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of `/` needed before anchor name

Your create an anchor with

```
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

and refer to it later with

```
<a href="http://www.exmaple.com#footer">Footer </a> // will work
```